# Pandas: count when condition is met in subgroups

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
        subgroup value
0         1      0
1         1      1
2         1      1
3         1      0
4         2      0
5         2      0
6         2      0
7         3      0
8         3      1
9         3      0
10        3      0
```

I need to add a column that add 1 whenever there is at least one value different than 0 in the different subgroups. Please, note that if the value 1 is repeated more than once in the same subgroup, it doesn't affect the count.
The result should be:

```
       subgroup  value   count
0         1      0        1
1         1      1        1
2         1      1        1
3         1      1        1
4         2      0        1
5         2      0        1
6         2      0        1
7         3      0        2
8         3      1        2
9         3      0        2
10        3      0        2
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Your results aren't consistent.  Why does the `count` column start at 1, even though a `1` has not been seen in value for group 1, but it *doesn't* increment by `1` at the start of group 3, but instead waits until a `1` has been seen

Comment: Because I need to assign the same value to the event. Maybe I should have specified that.

Comment: I understand that, but your results don't follow that behavior for group 3

Comment: In group 3 it was my error, I have fixed that, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using `shift` with -1 and 1 and `cumsum` the result

```
mask=(df.value.ne(df.value.shift()))&(df.value.ne(df.value.shift(-1)))
mask.cumsum()
Out[18]: 
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     2
9     2
10    2
Name: value, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `merge` and `groupby`

```
df.merge(df.groupby('subgroup').value.sum().gt(0).cumsum().reset_index(name='out'))
```

```
    subgroup  value  out
0          1      0    1
1          1      1    1
2          1      1    1
3          1      0    1
4          2      0    1
5          2      0    1
6          2      0    1
7          3      0    2
8          3      1    2
9          3      0    2
10         3      0    2
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid out to be an index? because afterwards I don't need the column value anymore and whenever I try to hide/drop it, also out disappears

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? `out` is not an index in the final result.

Comment: I would like to drop the value column, and then work more on the df, adding other columns and so on. The first problem is that after your code, if I drop the column value also out disappears. The second is that when I add other columns out disappears as well (just value remains)